# what am i doing wrong with transaction Rollback in python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I  m using the following code in Python-mysql. Rollback isn't working, can someone please point out what am I doing wrong.

```
try:
    cnx.start_transaction()
    

    engine=connectEngine.connect()
    df_ord_main.to_sql('maintbl', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', chunksize = 1000, index=False)
    df_ord_mainDets.to_sql('Detstbl', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', chunksize = 1000, index=False)
    

    if cnx.is_connected() == False:
             except Error as error:
             print(error)
             cnx.rollback()

finally:
    
    cursor.close()
    if cnx.in_transaction == True:
        cnx.rollback()
    if cnx.is_connected() == True:
            cnx.close()
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "rollback isn't working".  What happens when you run your code, and what do you expect to happen?  Please [edit] the question to include any error messages and tracebacks.

Comment: Records get added to mainTbl , even if there is error on second table 
Detstbl "df_ord_mainDets.to_sql('Detstbl',"

Comment: I'm not an expert on Pandas, but I would guess `df.to_sql` creates its own transaction.  You could check by setting `echo=True` when you create the engine, and seeing if there are `commit` statements in the ouput after the data is inserted.